# Chart error: Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have 4 series in my chart.
Method below works well and I see the result.

```
private void ChartSettings(AxisEnabled axisY2Enabled,
                                      bool enabledS1, bool enabledS2, bool enabledS3, bool enabledS4,
                                      bool isVisibleInLegendS1, bool isVisibleInLegendS2, bool isVisibleInLegendS3, bool isVisibleInLegendS4,
                                      string legendTextS1, string legendTextS2, string legendTextS3, string legendTextS4,
                                      string yValueMembersS1, string yValueMembersS2, string yValueMembersS3, string yValueMembersS4)
    {
        chartShow.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = axisY2Enabled;

        chartShow.Series["S1"].Enabled = enabledS1;
        chartShow.Series["S2"].Enabled = enabledS2;
        chartShow.Series["S3"].Enabled = enabledS3;
        chartShow.Series["S4"].Enabled = enabledS4;
        chartShow.Series["S1"].IsVisibleInLegend = isVisibleInLegendS1;
        chartShow.Series["S2"].IsVisibleInLegend = isVisibleInLegendS2;
        chartShow.Series["S3"].IsVisibleInLegend = isVisibleInLegendS3;
        chartShow.Series["S4"].IsVisibleInLegend = isVisibleInLegendS4;

        chartShow.Series["S1"].LegendText = legendTextS1;
        chartShow.Series["S2"].LegendText = legendTextS2;
        chartShow.Series["S3"].LegendText = legendTextS3;
        chartShow.Series["S4"].LegendText = legendTextS4;
        chartShow.Series["S1"].YValueMembers = yValueMembersS1;
        chartShow.Series["S2"].YValueMembers = yValueMembersS2;
        chartShow.Series["S3"].YValueMembers = yValueMembersS3;
        chartShow.Series["S4"].YValueMembers = yValueMembersS4;

        chartShow.Series["S1"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chartShow.Series["S2"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chartShow.Series["S3"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chartShow.Series["S4"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;

        chartShow.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
        chartShow.Series["S4"].XValueMember = "Date";
    }
```

but, when I refactor the code above to:

```
private void ChartSettings(AxisEnabled axisY2Enabled,
                                      bool[] enabledAndIsVisibleInLegend, string[] legendText, string[] yValueMembers,
                                      AxisType[] axisType)
    {
        chartShow.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = axisY2Enabled;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )
        {
            chartShow.Series["S" + i].Enabled = enabledAndIsVisibleInLegend[i - 1];
            chartShow.Series["S" + i].IsVisibleInLegend = enabledAndIsVisibleInLegend[i - 1];
            chartShow.Series["S" + i].LegendText = legendText[i - 1];
            chartShow.Series["S" + i].YAxisType = axisType[i - 1];
            chartShow.Series["S" + i].XValueMember = "Date";
            chartShow.Series["S" + i].YValueMembers = yValueMembers[i - 1];
        }

        chartShow.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = interval;
    }
```

I get this error: Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series.

Any help/note?
Thank you.

**Edit:**

An example of calling methods:

```
ChartSettingsForShow(AxisEnabled.False,
                                     false, false, false, true,
                                     false, false, false, true,
                                     "", "", "", legendText,
                                     "", "", "", yValueMembers);

ChartSettingsForShow(AxisEnabled.False,
                                 new bool[] { false, false, false, true },
                                 new string[] { "", "", "", legendText },
                                 new string[] { "", "", "", yValueMembers },
                                 new AxisType[] { AxisType.Primary, AxisType.Primary, AxisType.Primary, AxisType.Primary });
```

yValueMembers is a string that correspond to a column name in a DataTable.

Comment: You don't show how the Series are created or where and how the data are bound. What are the values of yValueMembers? Really always just one data field name?

Comment: @TaW Series are created from properties window in VS.